# is it ok to keep embeded database file open during running time of my app?

Tags: embedded-database

I am using an embedded database file, on start up of my app, i will open the database file, only when the app exit, i close the database file, is it a best practice?

should i use it  the traditional open-update-close fashion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this approach as long as:

- the database isn't shared
- keeping an connection open does not require significant resources
- you can safely release any allocated resources when your application crashes or terminates unexpectedly.